# JNDI InvalidNameException

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, jndi

I'm always getting an error when getting a name from my active directory server. The error is the following:

```
javax.naming.InvalidNameException: Invalid name: "CN=»OGMA Serviço LAN/WAN",cn=Recipients,cn=Users,,dc=intra
```

After googling a bit, I found the following information

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4307193
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/names/syntax.html

As you can see, I tried both with the parser approach and the composite name approach, but the error continues! What am I missing?

Here's my code that does those operations:

```
DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext( (Hashtable<String,String>) env);

Name n2 = new CompositeName().add(usersContainer);
NamingEnumeration contentsEnum = ctx.list(n2);

String[] attName = {"cn"};

while ( contentsEnum.hasNext() ) {
    NameClassPair ncp = (NameClassPair) contentsEnum.next();
    NameParser ldapParser = ctx.getNameParser("");

    String name = ncp.getName() + "," + usersContainer;
    Name n = ldapParser.parse(name);

    ctx.lookup(n);
```

The variable `name` is `"CN=»OGMA Serviço LAN/WAN" + cn=Recipients,cn=Users,,dc=intra`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you're doing anything so elaborate in the first place. If you had used `Context.listBindings()` instead of `Context.list(),` you could avoid building the name and the lookup altogether, as you would already have both the name and the binding already. Your code would reduce to:

```
NamingEnumeration<Binding> contentsEnum = ctx.listBindings(n2);

String[] attName = {"cn"};

while ( contentsEnum.hasNext() ) {
    Binding binding = contentsEnum.next();
    Object o = binding.getObject();
    // etc, whatever you were intending to do with the result of lookup(), which is now in 'o'.
}
```